# wordpress вывести посты категории

Tags: wordpress

Помогите вывести, уже устал пробовать)

```
<?php

                                $posts = get_posts( array(
                                    'orderby' => 'id',
                                    'category'  => 1,
                                    'posts_per_page' => 999
                                ) );
                                if ( $posts ) {
                                foreach ( $posts as $post ) :
                                    setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

                                                  <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                                                       <p><?php the_content(); ?></p>

                                <?php
                                endforeach; 
                                wp_reset_postdata();
                                }
                    ?>
```

не работает , так же пробовал WP_Query тоже не работает, есть рабочий способ на сегодняшний день?

Comment: Проверьте, что в рубрике с id=1 есть хотя бы одна запись.

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще:

```
<?php
$posts = get_posts( array(
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'category'  => 1,
    'numberposts' => -1         // -1 означает все записи
    ) );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
    ?>
    <h4><?php $post->post_title; ?></h4>
    <p><?php $post->post_content; ?></p>    
    <?php
}
?>
```